How do I write a code that posts into X (formerly twitter) using Tweepy and free X API?
I have tried using api.update_status() which gives the error:

453 - You currently have access to a subset of X API V2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.x.com/en/portal/product

and client.create_tweet() which gives the error:

Your client app is not configured with the appropriate oauth1 app permissions for this endpoint.

Does this mean that we can't post on Twitter using the free version of API?
The following is the snippet I've written -
from config import API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN,         ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,BEARER_TOKEN
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY,API_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

client =     tweepy.Client(BEARER_TOKEN,API_KEY,API_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,wait_on_r ate_limit=True)
#api.update_status("Hello World")
client.create_tweet(text = "Hello World")
print("Tweeted")

P.S I have did the user authentication settings in the developer portal too.

This question is similar to: errors when trying to tweet using tweepy. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
